# Determine if class is a subclass of a type with multiple generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Given the following class hierarchy

```
public abstract class MyGenericClass<T1, T2> 
{
    public T1 Foo { get; set; }
    public T2 Bar { get; set; }
}

public class BobGeneric : MyGenericClass<int, string>{}
public class JimGeneric : MyGenericClass<System.Net.Cookie, System.OverflowException>{}
```

I would have thought that I could do the following

```
//All types in the assembly containing BobGeneric and JimGeneric
var allTypes = _asm.GetTypes();  

//This works for interfaces, but not here 
var specialTypes = allTypes.Where(x => typeof(MyGenericClass<,>).IsAssignableFrom(x))

//This also fails
typeof(BobGeneric).IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyGenericClass<,>)).Dump();
```

How would I determine in code that `BobGeneric` inherits from `MyGenericClass`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx):

```
typeof(BobGeneric).GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyGenericClass<,>)).Dump();
```

You can imagine that method as "stripping away" all generic type arguments, just leaving the raw definition with its formal generic parameters.

If it does not work directly on `BobGeneric`, you may have to navigate upwards in the type hierarchy till you find `MyGenericClass<...,...>` (or any type for which [`IsGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype.aspx) returns `true`).

Comment: Had to change to `typeof(MyGenericClass<,>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BobGeneric).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())`, but many thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: I went from one type parameter to two. And `typeof(MyGeneric<>)` didn't work anymore. It was due to the missing comma `<,>`.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: Indeed, you can have several classes with the same name, as long as they accept different numbers of generic parameters. Hence, `MyGeneric<>`, `MyGeneric<,>`, `MyGeneric<,,>`, etc., are all different classes.